# java xpath should show subnodes only without attributes, but shows all

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a simple example xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<testCars>
    <cars id="0">
        <color id="0">Black</color>
        <color id="1">Orange</color>
    </cars>
    <cars id="1">
        <color id="0">Blue</color>
        <color id="1">Grey</color>
    </cars>
    <cars>
        <color id="0>">Red</color>
        <color id="1>">Green</color>
    </cars>
 </testCars>
```

First I use DocumentBuilder to parse that file, and then I use xpath to get the things I want.
I would use the expression and xpath to get the color 0 of car 1:

```
String expression = String.format("/testCars/cars[@id=\"%s\"]/color[@id=\"%s\"]",1,0);
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
System.out.println(nodeList.item(0).getTextContent());
```

And I get Blue, as I should. But lets say I want the color 0 of a card without an ID, it should be Red.

So I change the expression to

```
String expression = String.format("/testCars/cars/color[@id=\"%s\"]",0);
```

But now the result is Black. It just takes the first node, although I want it to take the one without any attributes on it.

Does Xpath have some specific command to explicitly select nodes without an attribute? Or do I need to restructe the xml file?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the `cars` element with no attributes, use `cars[not(@*)]`. To select a `cars` element with no `@id` attribute, use `cars[not(@id)]`.

Comment: thanks, but that appears to not work. So the expression is now : "/testCars/cars[not(@*)]/color[@id=\"0\"]" But after evaluating the expression there is no node found. Both version, also excluding specifically id does not find a node.

Comment: if I remove the color part, it does find the one node without an attribute ....

Comment: My bad, there were extra ">" in the color id of the last one.